# Does a carbon fiber seat help karting performance and protect ribs?

Tags: injuries, performance, kart-racing

I found a karting seat that is made from carbon-fiber here:

- http://www.ribtect.com/RibtectSeat_Original.html

On that page, it claims:

> **To Improve Performance:**
>   The Ribtect seat helps the chassis and driver to work better. Keeping the kart rolling free and providing a better launch out of the turns. Connecting more of the kart to the driver for a better feel of the chassis. Lowering the fatigue level of the driver, allowing for better concentration and improved consistency and lower lap times.
>
> **To Prevent Rib Injury:**
>   The Ribtect Seat is designed to reduce the amount of rib injuries to karters. Thus, keeping more people involved and happy with the great sport of karting.

I'm wondering if these claims are significant?  Does such a seat provide a significant benefit to rib protection as compared to using a good vest like [this one](http://kracer.com.au/other-stuff/bengio-bumper.html)?  Does such a seat provide any significant performance benefit (e.g. more than 0.25% faster) in outdoor karting such as at [Sonoma raceway](https://simracewaydrivingschool.com/organizer/simraceway-performance-karting-center/) for a driver near the top of the field in Senior [Rotax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotax_Max_Challenge)?

Comment: I think this would be much better suited to the Skeptics.SE site - which focuses on evidence based discussion of claims.